# Call an existing method inside viewmodel

Tags: ajax, mvvm, knockout.js, datatables

I would like to know if it is possible to call a method inside another method in a view model

In my attached: function I have an ajax method to display all customers

```
           attached: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/listusers/GetContractorList",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                headers: appsecurity.getSecurityHeaders(),

                success: function (result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        var mappedContractorList = $.map(result, function (item) {
                            return new GKContractorObj(item);
                        });

                        viewmodel.ContractorList(mappedContractorList);

                        tableObj = $('#tblContractorsList').DataTable();

                    }
                },
                failure: function (error) {
                    logger.logError('Failed to contractor list', 'Error', null, true);
                }
            })
```

I want to call the method inside attached: function in another data-bind method out here

```
showGKContractors: 
    function () {
                //Some Logic 
                //Call to  url (attached:method): "/api/listusers/GetContractorList" 
                (without having to rewrite code)
               }
```

How do I get around doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Just move the portion of the code inside attached that you want to call in more than one place, into a brand new function that is visible to both your view models, e.g

```
makeAjaxRequest: function () {
   ///1. the code you want to move from inside your attached function
}
```

Then call the new function both your attached function and your showGkContractors

```
attached: function () {

    makeAjaxRequest();
   ///2. all the other code you don't want to move from attached
}

showGKContractors: function () {

            //1. Some Logic 
            //2. makeAjaxRequest();

           }
```

The new function could either be defined at the top of the page if both attached and showGKContractors are in the same .js file, or you could put it in a separate script file and reference it by namespace if you want

e.g in a separate file included on the web page above your GKContractors and attached files have a file with this script

```
 (function (scope) {

scope.makeAjaxRequest: function () {
       ///1. the code you want to move from inside your attached function
       ///2. all the other code you don't want to move
    }

})(window.SharedNameSpace);
```

then in your attached and showGKContractors file(s) you could call the makeAjaxRequest function
by calling

```
window.SharedNameSpace.makeAjaxReuest();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do with shared logic is to move it out of your view models and put it in a shared class that can be used by both view models.

If you're actually trying to trigger something in another view model, then you should use an event or a message to do so. There are several libraries out there that support this.